# php and javascript contact form is not getting execute

Tags: javascript, php, permissions, contacts

I have a contact form that uses javascript for validation.

There are two websites:

[TEP.com](http://www.tep.com/contact/information/)

and

[UESAZ.com](https://www.uesaz.com/contact/information/)

The form on UES works.
The form on TEP does not.

Both forms are the same.
Both forms are three files with the following code:

index.php:

```
<div class="FormLayout">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $("#contact-us-form button").click(function() {
                        $('#ValidationMessages').hide();
                        $('#SubmitSuccess').hide();
                        $('.validationerror').removeClass('validationerror');
                        $.post("processing.php", $("#contact-us-form").serialize(), function(data) {
                            if($('status', data).text() == "missingFields") {
                                $('#ValidationMessages ul').text('');
                                $('messages message', data).each(function(index, label) {
                                    $('#ValidationMessages ul').append('<li>' + $(label).text() + '</li>');
                                    var field = $(label).attr('field');
                                    $('label[for="' + field + '"]').addClass("validationerror");
                                    $('input[name="' + field + '"]').addClass("validationerror");
                                    $('select[name="' + field + '"]').addClass("validationerror");
                                    $('textarea[name="' + field + '"]').addClass("validationerror");
                                    $('.formvalue_' + field).addClass("validationerror");
                                });
                                $('#ValidationMessages').show();
                            } else if($('status', data).text() == "success") {
                                $('#SubmitSuccess').show();
                                document.getElementById('contact-us-form').reset();
                            }
                        }, "xml");
                    });
                });

            </script>
            <form action="#" method="post" id="contact-us-form">
                <label for="cname">Full Name</label>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="cname" class="input input_wide" maxlength="250" />
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <label for="cemail">Email</label>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="cemail" class="input input_wide" maxlength="250" />
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <label for="caccount">Account Number</label>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="caccount" class="input input_wide" maxlength="10" />
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <label for="cphone">Phone</label>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="cphone" class="input input_wide" maxlength="50"  />
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <label for="cquestion">Message</label>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <textarea name="cquestion" rows="5" cols="28" class="input input_wide"></textarea>
                <div style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
                <button class="button button-submit" type="button"> <span>Submit</span> </button>
            </form>
```

processing.php:

```
    <?php 
include(substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"],0,(strlen($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) * -1)) . "/templates/xhr_prepend.php");
include(_CODEDIR . '/TEP/Forms/Contact/Contact_processing.php'); 
?>
```

Contact_processing.php:

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml");

// Include Util Class
include(_CODEDIR . '/shared/Util.inc.php');

$validationFailed = false;
$validationMessages = array();

if(trim($_POST['cname']) == '') {
    $validationFailed = true;
    $validationMessages['cname'] = "Please provide your Full Name.";
}

if(trim($_POST['cemail']) == '') {
    $validationFailed = true;
    $validationMessages['cemail'] = "Please provide your Email address.";
} else {
    if(preg_match("/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/", $_POST['cemail']) == 0) {
        $validationFailed = true;
        $validationMessages['cemail'] = "Please provide a valid Email address.";
    }
}

if(trim($_POST['caccount']) != '') {
    if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $_POST['caccount']) == 0) {
        $validationFailed = true;
        $validationMessages['caccount'] = "Please provide a valid 10 digit Account Number.";
    }
}

if(trim($_POST['cphone']) == '') {
    $validationFailed = true;
    $validationMessages['cphone'] = "Please provide your Phone number.";
}

if(trim($_POST['cquestion']) == '') {
    $validationFailed = true;
    $validationMessages['cquestion'] = "Please provide a Message.";
}

print '<Processing>';

if($validationFailed) {
    print '<status>missingFields</status>';
    print '<messages>';
    foreach($validationMessages as $key => $val) {
        print '<message field="' . Util::strCleanOutput($key). '">' . Util::strCleanOutput($val) . '</message>';
    }
    print '</messages>';
} else {

    $emailBody = '<p><b>Contact Us Request</b></p>';

    $emailBody .= '<b>Full Name:</b> ' . Util::strCleanOutput($_POST['cname']) . '<br />';
    $emailBody .= '<b>Email:</b> ' . Util::strCleanOutput($_POST['cemail']) . '<br />';
    if(trim($_POST['caccount']) == '') {
        $emailBody .= '<b>Account Number:</b>Not Provided<br />';
    } else {
        $emailBody .= '<b>Account Number:</b> ' . Util::strCleanOutput($_POST['caccount']) . '<br />';
    }
    $emailBody .= '<b>Phone:</b> ' . Util::strCleanOutput($_POST['cphone']) . '<br />';
    $emailBody .= '<b>Message:</b><br />' . nl2br(Util::strCleanOutput($_POST['cquestion'])) . '';

    Util::SendMail("sa45762@tep.com", "webmaster@tep.com", "Contact Us - TEP", $emailBody);

    print "<status>success</status>";
}

print '</Processing>';

?>
```

There is no difference in either site's code other than the following:

UES:

permissions are set to: RWX

TEP:

permissions are set to: RW

I believe it's a permissions problem in that TEP's contact form is not set to execute.

Any ideas? Thank you. :)

Comment: if you believe its a permission problem have you tried changing the permissions? And explain more on does "not work" and does "not execute", for instance if a php script does not execute usually it gets downloaded (or in this case the script text will be in your `data` variable)

Comment: This is the problem. I don't have the ability to set the permissions on the file and was told php does not need to be chmod.

I disagree. Your thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps getting in touch with the person who has the right to change permission is the first thing to do. Then you could update the question with more detailed result for others to give input.